# Nested Queries with Select Statement

Tags: oracle, nested, subquery

I am new to Oracle. I have a table where there are multiple restriction groups that are assigned to users. Every group of user belong to a userregionID.
I have to display a list of userregionID where users are assigned more than 1 restriction group.

My Tables

```
user - Id, userregionid
userRestriction - userId, restrictionGroup
```

For example,

User Table

```
EID-999 | 12345
EID- 888 | 12345
D-900 | 2322
F-943 | 6767
```

UserRestriction Table

```
UserId | RestrictionGroup

EID-999| A1
EID-888 | B1
EID-999 | C1
F-943 | Z1
F-943 | X1
```

So, my output should come like

```
UserRegionId | Count of Users having restriction Group >1
12345          | 1 
6767           | 1
```

because user `EID-999` and `F-943` belong to userregionId `12345` and `6767` respectively and they are assigned more than 1 restriction group.

My Effort

I have written a query that displays the list of users having > 1 restrictionGroup within the same userregionID
but I am clueless on how to proceed further and convert this query into a nested query that can only fetch the count and userregionID from the entire database.

My query

```
select distinct ec.userId, e.userregionid, 
count(distinct ec.restrictionGroup) over (partition by ec.userId)
from user e, userRestriction ec
where e.userregionid = '12345' and e.Id= ec.userId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not need a nested-query here and a `INNER JOIN` as below can help you.

```
select  u.userregionid, count(ur.userId)
from userRestriction ur, USR u
where ur.userId=u.id
group by ur.userId , u.userregionid
having count(ur.userId) >1;
```

PS: A [DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=22faf12a82bef74695690ffbc070a0c6) here can help you to visualize.

Comment: Hi, this is still not giving proper output. I added some more data. It should show count ```1``` for userregionid ```12345``` and ```3``` for userregionid ```6767```.

Comment: I feel the output you have shared is aligned correctly. `EID-999` belongs to `A1` & `C1` so count is 2, in similar manner `F-900` belongs to `X1`, `G1` & `H1`. Same applies to `F-800` & `F-943`.  In case if you are looking for grouping by `userregionid`, then this latest addition to db-fiddle can help  you https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=87fd8a8dd67945a9d571d4eed756cdcf 

`select  u.userregionid, count(u.userregionid)
from userRestriction ur, USR u
where ur.userId=u.id
group by u.userregionid
having count(u.userregionid) >1;`